# PHP cannot resolve hostname

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm learning docker for my first project using Slim framework (PHP). I created a dockerfile to build an image with all the source code in it. When I run the image with the run command it shows me

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sat Jun 15 09:41:14 2019] Failed to listen on  127.0.0.1:8080 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve)
```

Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM php:7-alpine
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD [ "php", "-S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t public" ]
```

Docker run command is:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --network="host" --expose 8080 --name cm2 collection_manager_1
```

Don't know how I can fix this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you really want to listen on localhost? I think it should be -S 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: When I try with -S 0.0.0.0:8080 I'm getting the same error (but failt to listen on 0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CMD` [syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) seems to have some problem. All the arguments in the command should be comma separated and inside the double quotes.

I made a slight change in `Dockerfile` and it worked.

```
FROM php:7-alpine
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD [ "php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080", "-t", "html" ]
```

`docker build -t testimage:v1 .`

```
[mchawre@jumphost try]$ docker run -it --rm --network="host" --expose 8080 --name testrun testimage:v1
PHP 7.3.6 Development Server started at Sat Jun 15 11:50:19 2019
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
Document root is /var/www/html
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

**NOTE:** Change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 so that you can hit the php using public/private ip of your machine rather than just localhost.